# Who pays the cost for not passing by const reference

Tags: c++

Given:

```
void foo(std::vector<int> v);

void bar()
{
    std::vector<int> v = ...; // many items
    foo(v);
}
```

What in a profiling tool would show as the hot path? Would it be the `std::vector<T>`'s copy constructor, the runtime or the operating system? I remember in school (I'm not a C++ dev, just work with some) that this will copy `v` and that can take time. I do know that a signature like:

```
void foo(const std::vector<int>& v);
```

avoids this potentially costly copy operation.

Comment: Err, you do. The operating system has nothing to do with it.

Comment: who is "you" in the program?

Comment: This code will get inlined heavily and so I'm not sure if any meaningful function name will show up during profiling. Also,`std::vector<int>`'s copy constructor is just calling into`std::memcpy`. `memcpy` is doing all the work.

Comment: What part of the code copies the contents of the `vector`, in this case? `Vector`'s copy constructor, obviously.

Comment: profiler would show the extra copy at the calling site.

Comment: It may have been a while since you studied C++ in school. We now also have the option of `foo(std::move(v))` which avoids the expensive copy of `v`, at the expense of leaving `v` empty. The contents of `v` are moved into `foo`. (This was introduced in the C++11 Standard)

Answer (score 5):

Copying `std::vector<T>` by value does, potentially, three things:

1. Memory manager (C++ runtime or custom allocator) searches for available memory block for the new vector in its stashes. If it can find it, then it goes to step #3.
2. Memory manager (C++ runtime or custom allocator) requests more memory from the OS. This call itself is relatively cheap (as much as a syscall can be), because the OS gives memory in lazy mode - actual allocation is happening on the first write to the requested VM page.
3. Compiler generated code (application) does in-place `new` with copy c-tor for each element in the new vector if `T` is not trivially copy-constructible. Otherwise, `memcpy()` or it's optimized vectorized (in `sse` sense) counterpart is called. Just before the first time the new memory is written, if it was acquired from the OS in #2, the OS will need to actually allocate the new VM page and that may trigger RAM access (hardware), TLB lookup (hardware + OS) swapping in/out (OS).

In your specific example `T` is trivially copy-constructible so the worst case overhead would be `C++` runtime memory block lookup + `sbrk()` syscall + `memcpy()` call.

Comment: Huh... so that's where all my parentheses went! :D

Answer (score 2):

The decision to take an argument by value versus by const reference should take into account what the function plans on doing with the value. If the function only plans on reading from the existing value, then a const reference is the most efficient choice. If the called function would have made a copy of the referenced object as part of its implementation, then passing by value has a potential to be faster as the caller can move construct the argument if it makes sense, and remove the need for a copy.

```
void foo(std::vector<int> v);

void bar()
{
    std::vector<int> v = ...; // many items
    foo(std::move(v)); // no copy needed here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can *expect* the copy constructor of `std::vector<int>` to be called.

A clever compiler is permitted to optimise out the value copy if there are absolutely no side effects in its doing to. Futhermore, if the function *definition* is marked `inline` then a value copy will not be taken if the compiler honours your request (it doesn't have to).

You're best bet is indeed to pass `v` by `const` reference. Not only does this obviate the value copy, but it also means that the function being called cannot modify the argument passed.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler only have to emit code that acts `as-if` it runs your code, that is the **observable behavior** is the same.

The likely hotspot should be either the assignment operator in `bar` as you need to create the original vector or a copy constructor.

In your example the compiler can rewrite it in different ways, if it can reason out that `v` is never used in `bar` again so it might implement the call `foo(v);` as `foo(std::move(v))` (like @MSalters already mentioned).
This leaves `v` as a dead object in `bar()` which is then destroyed.

Alternatively the compiler might just create the `vector` on the call stack and save itself a call to the destructor, effectively making the call-by-value free.